# Generate report with multiple features using Java

Tags: java, eclipse, report, pdf-generation

I am using BIRT in eclipse to generate my report and I found out I can't include a table of content (ToC) inside the report. I tried to store sub-titles and page numbers in an array and display them but that's causes various problems.

I need a tool to create a generic report (in PDF format) that supports :

- Retrieving data from database.
- Custom page layout : Portrait and landscape in the same report.
- Header & Footer.
- Tables.
- Images.
- Page breaks : Ex: Split tables and add the table header in the new page.
- ToC : I need a main ToC in the beginning of the report and multiple sub-ToC inside it.

It's fine if your suggested tool can't do some of the above and instead it's doable with java.

If I can't include Portrait and landscape layouts in the same report, then I need it to be able to combine multiple reports and update page numbers.

**EDIT :** I am currently looking into using Jasper Report or Pentaho. Still searching for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasper report will definitely serve all your needs. it will

1. Retrieve data from database.
2. Although, the JasperPrint objects does not support mixed page formats, there is a work-around for this. The entire report orientation can be changed to Landscape which can easily accommodate the data in the Portrait format.

[image]

3. The header/footers can be configured easily.
4. Tables and images can be included.
5. You can see the page break example [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-how-introduce-page-break-after-pre-defined-number-rows-table-component).
6. [This](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/jasperreports-36-creating-simple-one-page-toc-your-report) example illustrates the simple example of creating TOC.

Comment: Thanks but I don't really understand the page orientation workaround. Can you share a tutorial, example, article, link or anything I can use to apply the this workaround?

Comment: I have added a image. This is what I mean and it served our purpose.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I can't do that. It's the client's wish. I'm currently using BIRT. I'll post an answer when I have time.